# LINQ select property from object in query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of recipients to send a message, but I want to exclude those from a certain Role, the problem is that I have this:

```
var recipients = (from up in _db.UserProfiles
                  join ms in _db.MembershipEntities
                      on up.UserId equals ms.UserId
                  join st in _db.Studios
                      on up.StudioId equals st.StudioId
                  select new
                  {
                      up.UserId,
                      up.UserName,
                      up.StudioId,
                      st.Name,
                      ms.Roles
                  }).ToList();
```

And the result is what I want, only that the query returns an object Role which has a RoleID and a RoleName, so Im not sure how to select the RoleName so I can specify which role I want to exclude.

Comment: Could you give us a small sample set (input, output, wanted output, why)?

Comment: You should start by editing your scrollbar away my friend.

Comment: Why not exclude it in the join?

Comment: Do you want to only return users from the database if they have a given role or would you rather return all users to memory and then filter based on a given role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `where` clause to the query which filters the users within a certain role:

```
where ms.Roles.All(role => role.RoleName != "<insert role name>")
```

Your complete query will look like this:

```
(from up in _db.UserProfiles
    join ms in _db.MembershipEntities on up.UserId equals ms.UserId
    where ms.Roles.All(role => role.RoleName != "<insert role name>")
    join st in _db.Studios on up.StudioId equals st.StudioId
    select new { up.UserId, up.UserName, up.StudioId, st.Name, ms.Roles})
    .ToList();
```